# Make Live UEFI BIOS Compatible?

Tags: linux, bios, uefi, kali-linux, liveusb

I recently created a live Kali Linux image on my flash drive. It seems, however, a couple of my other computers come from the BIOS days... when I try to boot from my flash drive, it says “No operating system found!”

I was able to boot this on my modern UEFI laptop just fine, so I know it’s a compatibility issue. Is there a way to make a live disto backwards-compatible with UEFI? Do I simply need to add an extra boot sector with gparted or something? Or is the problem the fact that it’s a GPT table???

Comment: *"I recently created a live Kali Linux image on my flash drive"* - using what method?

Comment: I simply used Rufus to install the Kali Linux ISO. Why? Was there a different version I was supposed to use?

Comment: https://www.kali.org/download-kali-linux-revealed-book/

Answer (score 2):

See the askubuntu post
[Ubuntu live from USB with full persistence and NTFS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/936633/ubuntu-live-from-usb-with-full-persistence-and-ntfs)
describing how to use
[mkusb-dus](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb)
to create a persistent live drive.

More info is found in :

- Ubuntu help
   [Installation/UEFI-and-BIOS](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/UEFI-and-BIOS)
- Ubuntu forums
  [Portable installed system that boots in UEFI as well as in BIOS mode](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2213631&page=7&p=13468260#post13468260)

Comment: Thanks for your answer - it seems they are recommending NOT upgrading the system on a flash drive :/ makes sense given the speed I’ve been experiencing these days. At least I appear to have a spare M.2 SSD handy...